# Hive Regex not working

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to create a hive external table using `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe` for analising some `Log4J` logs.

However my `regex` is not working even when it's ok when testing in http://www.regexr.com/.

My problem is when I have multiline logs, for instance, an exception log with it's corresponding StackTrace.

Here is an example:

```
@@@@ 2015-09-29T11:20:45,549 INFO MYHOSTNAME my-app org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: name
    ...] @@@@
```

I've added a pattern on the start and end of the log to help extract it when there is multilines.

This is my regex:

```
@@@@ (.{23}) ([\\w]+) ([\\w]+) ([\\w\\-]+) ([\\w\\.$]+) ([\\s\\S]+) @@@@
```

And this is my table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE log4j(
    dt STRING,
    level STRING,
    host STRING,
    app_name STRING,
    clazz STRING,
    message STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "@@@@ (.{23}) ([\\w]+) ([\\w]+) ([\\w\\-]+) ([\\w\\.$]+) ([\\s\\S]+) @@@@")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'hdfs://localhost:9000/logs/';
```

With single line logs it works ok, but with multilines like the one on the example, it extracts several lines with all columns null.

Comment: Can you try adding `(?s)` at the beginning of the regex? Like here https://regex101.com/r/qF0rD1/1

Comment: Didn't work, same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

Then Hadoop will **first** break up the input by line (`\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n`), and **second** feed each input line into *RegexSerDe*.  This is why you're unable to get a multiline input into a single-row output using `TEXTFILE`.  Instead, try using:

```
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
```

And setting the Hadoop configuration property `textinputformat.record.delimiter` to whatever string separates two records in your input.  For your data, one sample delimiter might be `@@@@\n@@@@` or `@@@@\r\n@@@@`.  Keep in mind that setting this delimiter removes the matching text from the data, so your processed records won't have `@@@@` in them.

One way to test this out before changing any config files would be to set it in your Hive shell session before running the query:

```
set textinputformat.record.delimiter=@@@@\n@@@@
```